# Spontaneous high pitches & loud squeal in headset connected to Mac USB port

Tags: audio

This has happened 4 times on my MacBook Pro Retina in the last 6 months but also on two other Macs. Beats headsets to cheap Logitec. It is high volume, high pitch, spontaneous, comes out of no-where and definitely damaging to ears.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Needs more info to try to help, please edit your question - always the same headset? always the same 'cheap logitech'? … & *what* logitech? USB audio device? What Mac, what OS, what drivers, if any?? .  [completely incidentally, once met the 'original' Richard Jobson - nice man… assuming your avatar name is an 'into the valley' reference ;)

Comment: USB is generally terrible for streaming audio because of how it transfers data. What USB ports are they 2.0, or 3.0? What model MacBook Pro Retina?

Answer (score 1):

Have had similar problem.
It seems to be connected with Safari somehow.
This fix works, but you may need to do it when the sound comes back.

If Safari is running, quit it.
Hold down Shift key and launch Safari
Keep Shift depressed until your homepage appears
Releases Shift and clear history.

This seems to stop the problem for a time, but I have had to do it about once a month for the last 4 tor 5 months may

Comment: What leads you to think the problem is coming from Safari? Did you notice this on a particular web server?